# How to show the frequency of records that are 15 min away from one another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I have the data which looks like below

```
Date          Time         Route         
12Feb2018    12.17.00      NYC-BOS
12Feb2018    12.19.14      NYC-BOS
12Feb2018    21.07.05      SGF-XNA
13Feb2018    11.17.00      NYC-BOS
13Feb2018    11.19.14      NYC-BOS
13Feb2018    22.07.05      SGF-XNA
```

I want to see what trips depart within 15 min gap.

Here is what I have done,

I have converted Time into minutes and stored as mins column.

I used below code to create Matrix to see all possible combination of difference

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(data.mins, data.mins)), data.Route, data.Route)
df2
```

The output of this code is as follows:
[image]

Then I stacked it together

```
stacked = df2.stack()
dis = pd.DataFrame({'Routes': stacked.index.to_series(), 'Diff': stacked})[['Routes', 'Diff']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

The output is 
[image]

Now, I am filtering based on the diff column..

Is there a way to just do the frequency of Routes that are 15 min away from one another and also based on Date without going through the matrix method. The reason is that it doesn't run for huge data

Example, the output should be something like

```
Date         Route     Frequency
12Feb2018    NYC-BOS     2
12Feb2018    SGF-XNA     4
13Feb2018    NYC-BOS     3
```

Comment: So, in the example data you gave at the top, the answer result would be:
`NYC-BOS -> 3`
`SGF-XNA -> 0`?

Comment: Yes, The result would be 12Feb2018 NYC-BOS -> 2 12Feb2018 SGF-XNA -> 1 13Feb2018 NYC-BOS -> 2 –

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you are asking, could you give an example of before & after dataframes?